# How to traverse through a file and apply date in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm sure this has been answered but having trouble with my google search.

File is like this:

```
2020-01-01 10:33
2020-01-01 14:04
2020-01-01 17:22
2020-01-20 14:04
2020-01-21 03:33
2020-01-22 14:06
```

How do I traverse through each line and apply **date +"%b%d"** so that the file looks like:

```
Jan1 10:33
Jan1 14:04
Jan1 17:22
Jan20 14:04
Jan21 03:33
Jan22 14:06
```

Comment: Do you need this to be fast? Running a copy of `date` per line works well enough, but it's very slow compared to doing this in awk.

Comment: ...if you're happy with the slower but more obvious implementation, this is just a straightforward application of [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) - *How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?*, following its advice to loop over lines, calling `date` inside that loop. Indeed, I'd almost ask what you tried / where you got stuck trying to implement it yourself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is there a faster option? This file currently has 2 years of dates but it will continue to grow over time.

Comment: If you have dates across years, lit may not be a good idea to drop the year portion from the lines. Of course it is up to you.

Comment: @HuaCha unless your file has more than a few thousand dates, then simply looping with bash `date` is fine. The alternative is to use `awk`, see: [Gnu awk Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#Time-Functions) which will process the records in a more efficient manner.

Comment: ...to be clear, the first date format is for most purposes very much the better one. `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` dates can be sorted (by tools that just view them as text, without needing to know that `Jan` comes before `Feb` despite `F` coming before `J` in the alphabet), merged, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have basically two options.

1. using shell, loop over each line in your file, reading each line into a variable and output with date using the format `+'%b%d %H:%M'`; or
2. using GNU `awk`, create a *datespec* from each line, and pass to `mktime` to create a *timestamp* which can then be used with `strftime` to output the format `"%b%d %H:%M"`.

**Bash Solution**

```
while read -r line; do 
    date -d "$line" +'%b%d %H:%M'
done < file
```

**GNU awk Solution**

```
awk '{
    gsub(/[-:]/," ",$0)                # remove '-' and ':'
    ts=mktime($0 " 00")                # add " 00" creating datespec, create timestamp
    print strftime("%b%d %H:%M",ts)    # output new date format
}' file
```

(**note:** `mawk`, at least from version 1.3.3 on also supports `mktime` and `strftime`)

**Example Output**

In both cases the output is the same:

```
Jan01 10:33
Jan01 14:04
Jan01 17:22
Jan20 14:04
Jan21 03:33
Jan22 14:06
```

Look things over and let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Thanks! I used the first option. Worked like a charm.